# How to convert geth arhive to full node without loosing intermediate state

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, state-trie, archive-node, full-node

We have a geth node that runs with `--gcmode "archive"`. However, the recent growth of disk space is unsustainable and we want to change this to a full node. If I stop the node and just re-run it with `--gcmode "full"`:

1. Will we lose all the intermediate state in the node?
2. If not lost, will we be able to query old intermediate state?
3. Will the node start sync again from genesis (depending on `--syncmode` option) or will continue from where it stopped?

Given the time to resync an archive node if we need to run it again for research purposes, we don't want to lose the intermediate state that's already in our disk.